# Auto layout adjust bottom area in different devices IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

How to set up different Auto Layout constraints for different screen sizes?
Please see the screenshots. Please help me to how to cover the bottom space in different devices.

Iphone 7+

[image: Iphone 7+]

Iphone 7

[image: Iphone 7]

Iphone 5s

[image: Iphone 5s]

Thanks

Comment: You could give bottom constraint to Login Now button and set other constraints accordingly.

Comment: Put everything in UIView. Add constraints to that UIView as center horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Use should use promotional height constraint for the views height.

Answer (score 0):

you give your constrain that you given..

or you try to give constrain from bottom to that..

Answer (score 0):

Put all of these UI Components into a view

With the new view's bottom constraint add these 2 constraint: `greater than or equal to` and `less than or equal to` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set constant constraint for on device and take an outlet of that constraint. We cannot use size classes for this as these devices are with Compact width and Regular height.
Find the device using window or view height and change the constant value of the constraint accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about use `DeviceLayout`

Github https://github.com/cruisediary/DeviceLayout

you can set different Autolayout for different screen size

[image]

you can use cocoapod `pod "DeviceLayout"`

How to use

1. install `DeviceLayout` using Cocoapod
2. inherit your Auto Layout constraint (NSLayoutConstraint)
3. set your constaint of constraint for diffent screen size

in your case, you should set bottom spacing (Login Button to Bottom Layout) auto layout inherit `DeviceLayoutConstraint` and setup constaint differently